# How to add a click event on Vuetify headers?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have more than 5 tables.
I would like to add a click event on "v-data-table" 
headers that would be in charge of updating data source.

```js
<template>
      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="items['America']"
        :custom-sort="customSort"
        @click="registerPlace('America')"
      >
      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="items['Europe']"
        :custom-sort="customSort"
        @click="registerPlace('Europe')"
      >
</template>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      current_place: null,

      headers: [...],
      items: [...]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getTablesData();
  },
  methods: {
    registerPlace(place) {
        this.current_place = place;
    },
    customSort(items, sortBy, desc) { ... }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to have a callback function triggered by
click on table headers?
The above does not work.

Comment: It doesn't support `@click` for the headers, you need to use custom header rendering slots `header` or `header.<name>`

Answer (score 4):

You may need to use the `header.<name>` or `header` slot

the former is for editing an individual header, where the `<name>` is the key for the column.

Here is an example that replaces the 2nd column (Calories) with a button that triggers a console log function.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      singleSelect: false,
      selected: [],
      headers: [
      {
        text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
        align: 'left',
        sortable: false,
        value: 'name' },

      { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
      { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
      { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
      { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
      { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' }],

      desserts: [
      {
        name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
        calories: 159,
        fat: 6.0,
        carbs: 24,
        protein: 4.0,
        iron: '1%' },

      {
        name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
        calories: 237,
        fat: 9.0,
        carbs: 37,
        protein: 4.3,
        iron: '1%' },

      {
        name: 'Eclair',
        calories: 262,
        fat: 16.0,
        carbs: 23,
        protein: 6.0,
        iron: '7%' },

      {
        name: 'Cupcake',
        calories: 305,
        fat: 3.7,
        carbs: 67,
        protein: 4.3,
        iron: '8%' },

      {
        name: 'Gingerbread',
        calories: 356,
        fat: 16.0,
        carbs: 49,
        protein: 3.9,
        iron: '16%' },

      {
        name: 'Jelly bean',
        calories: 375,
        fat: 0.0,
        carbs: 94,
        protein: 0.0,
        iron: '0%' },

      {
        name: 'Lollipop',
        calories: 392,
        fat: 0.2,
        carbs: 98,
        protein: 0,
        iron: '2%' },

      {
        name: 'Honeycomb',
        calories: 408,
        fat: 3.2,
        carbs: 87,
        protein: 6.5,
        iron: '45%' },

      {
        name: 'Donut',
        calories: 452,
        fat: 25.0,
        carbs: 51,
        protein: 4.9,
        iron: '22%' },

      {
        name: 'KitKat',
        calories: 518,
        fat: 26.0,
        carbs: 65,
        protein: 7,
        iron: '6%' }] };



  },
  created() {
    this.console = console;
  }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.0.11/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.0.11/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      v-model="selected"
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :single-select="singleSelect"
      item-key="name"
      show-select
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template v-slot:header.calories >
        <button @click="console.log('you have clicked me')">Calories</button>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

The other option is to use the `header` slot, but then you need to handle the logic of adding the individual columns, so for each column, render your custom `<th>` tags.